AWS EC2 deployment occasionally fails with Laravel 11.x application & server stops working
I have a PHP 8.3, Laravel 11.x application that is currently hosted on an AWS EC2 instance. I deploy my latest changes every few days and regularly use composer update to keep my dependancies up-to date.
I run a bash script that performs the Laravel deploy which is as follows (see below), after running this if successful the latest version of the app is on the site. However sometimes occasionally something hangs in the vite 'building for production' process as shown in the screenshot below and the server stops working - I have to stop the server from the EC2 instance and then start it up again and then re-run my deploy.sh script again and it works.
Any ideas why this will occasionally break and I need to restart the server to re-run my deploy.sh for it to work again
#!/bin/bash

# Change directory to the proclubs directory
cd  /home/web/mywebapp

php artisan down || true

# Run git fetch to fetch changes from the remote repository
git fetch

# Run git pull to pull the latest changes from the remote repository
git pull

composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-dev

# Run php artisan optimize to optimize Laravel application
php artisan optimize

# Run npm run build to build assets using npm
npm run build

php artisan up

It is failing on the npm run build sometimes but not sure why


And what is the output of the failure?

@matiaslauriti no output it just hangs similar to the image above and I need to reboot the server

What EC2 instance are you using? I had a problem with a Laravel app on a tiny instance. It kept crashing until I added some swap space. Maybe you can monitor CPU and memory usage to see what's going on

@Zabs if it just hangs, I would say it is a memory issue. As 9uifranco said, try to monitor the CPU and Memory (RAM + Swap) usage while running the command

Thanks I'll try these steps I think it likely needs more memory only 1Gb currently
